# Which Class is calling the Serializer Class in Django REST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have two APIView classes and one ModelSerializer class. The APIView classes are using the serializer class. Is there any way to know which APIView class is calling the serializer class?
I need seperate representation_view for these 2 APIView.

**APIView Classes**

```
class OwnerAllListAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        all_list = ListName.objects.filter(owner=user).all()
        list_serializer = core_slr.ListNameSerializer(all_list, many=True)
        return response('Owner list', list_serializer.data, status.HTTP_200_OK)

class ListNameDetailAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        list_name = ListName.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs.get('list_name_id')).first()
        list_serializer = core_slr.ListNameSerializer(list_name)
        return response('list name detail view', list_serializer.data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**Serializer Class**

```
class ListNameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ListName
        fields = [
            'id', 'owner', 'name'
        ]

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super(ListNameSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        ret['owner'] = f"{instance.owner.first_name} {instance.owner.last_name}"
        ret['total_question'] = QuestionBank.objects.filter(list_name=instance).count()
        return ret
```

In the **to_representation** View, I just wanna to know which **API** is currently calling the serializer.

Comment: you can use the context parameter in the Serializer constructor

Comment: Got it. I am passing context info while calling serializer in the APIView. It works fine. Thank you @ElielVanHojman

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by accessing the context of the `Serializer`, like the following:

```
...
     def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super(ListNameSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        ret['owner'] = f"{instance.owner.first_name} {instance.owner.last_name}"
        ret['total_question'] = QuestionBank.objects.filter(list_name=instance).count()
        if self.context['view'].action == 'retrieve':
            pass # Do something
        elif self.context['view'].action == 'list':
            pass # Do the Other Thing
        return ret
```

Comment: it shows... KeyError: 'view' .... anyways, I've found the solution. Thank you @Radwan